# MongoDB: filter documents based on data from another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: `users` and `trips`.

User document example:

```
{
  "_id": 42
  "name": "David",
  "age": 27,
  "gender": "M",
  "status": "married"
}
```

Trip document example:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "uid": 42,
  "country": "Japan"
},

{
  "_id": 1,
  "uid": 42,
  "country": "France"
}
```

So in our example we see that David visited two countries: Japan and France.

**What I'd like to achieve**

I am working on an API that let the user query the data. A query could be

*single men above the age of 20 that visited Japan*

**The problem**

the countries data resides on another collection. That requires the use of `$lookup` which introduces a performance problem.

Let's say the query is *Men that visited Japan*. The usage of `$lookup` would require **to join** a large amount of data only to filter those where `country == Japan`

On top of that, I also want to implement pagination (let's say with `$skip` and `$limit`)

How can I efficiently apply such queries?

Comment: I don't see any other option to do this in the current collection structure, for efficiency and prevent $lookup, you can store countries in user's document in array.

Comment: @turivishal, I see. so would you suggest just set `countries` array to each `user`?

Comment: yes it would be better.